# Controlling webcam LED lights using java

Tags: java, opencv, webcam, javacv

I am making an java Application using javacv to record an video. Application can successfully record an video using webcam.

What I wanted to do is my webcam ([Intex IT-305WC](http://intexuae.com/?products=3web-camera-it-305wc-night-vision)) having some LED lights which get on/off according to light sensitivity, I want to make that LED lights continuously on when recording get stared through my application.

Is it possible to do that?

I searched on google I found some links related to android development using `PackageManager`(or somethink) etc. to control mobile phones flash.